# jquery causing errror: undefined when clicking on something that has no code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Im new to jquery, was messing around and had some lovely json being read in, updated all going fine.. Until I added a link to download the form to fill in.. and then on clicking it, it does the download but, also says "error: undefined" now, it seems to be because the code to populate the json results hasnt completed, but Im not sure how to avoid that.

```
<%@ Page Title="TEST Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="RSChanges.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script>

        function getg1()
        {
            showData = $('#group1');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/url1',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var content="";
                    var i;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.HDData.length; i++)
                    {
                            content += '<li>' + data.number+ '</li>';
                    }
                    showData.html(content);
                },
                error: function (xx, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert("error: " + xx.responseText);
                }
                });
        }

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('body').css('background-color', '#095BB5');
            $('body').css('color', 'white');
            $('a').css({ 'color': '#E0FFFF', 'textDecoration': 'underline' });
            $('#g1').click(function () { $('#group1').toggle(); });
            $('#group1').toggle();
            getg1();
        });
    </script>

       <div> Link to the current <a id="currentform" href="form.xls">download form</a><br /><br /></div>
    Current Active group1 (click <a id="g1">here</a> to show/hide)<br />
    <div class="group1" id="group1">(Loading please wait...)</div>
</asp:Content>
```

So, heres the code, I boiled a way some of the json updates, and changed the names of things to protect the innocent.

However, it still does this, fire up the page, and .. wham the moment you click on the form it says error: undefined in a popup box. if I click on the groups and expand them (only the 1 shown here) and wait till everythings downloaded, it doesnt seem to happen.  How can I not have the error box popup?

masterform -

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="RSChanges.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <style> 
        html, body{ height: 100%;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %></p>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw why are you using JavaScript to set some basic CSS properties when the page loads? Why not just use actual CSS, if they're _always_ going to be set? It would be more efficient and also better encapsulation.

Comment: Can you make a complete snippet that demonstrates the problem?  You've described a problem in click, but the click event handler is empty (and probably should be `$("#currentform").click...` - have a read of [mcve].

Comment: If you're referring to the alert in the ajax `error: ` callback, then that's nothing to do with the click event - it's because your ajax (server-side call) is failing (which is running at startup).  Add `console.log(xx, textStatus, errorThrown)` to see the actual error.

Comment: @freedomn-m this was as near MCVE as I could get this is a copy of the entire page with the URL changed!   the currentform.click was me trying to override any click event it may have generated. It also shows no errors in the console..  And as said the error only happens before ajax has completed,if you wait, it works fine.  The error still occurs without that line as that was me trying to override, so I have removed

Comment: @ADyson because its going to be part of something bigger..

Comment: Ok well maybe it makes sense in that context then. Anyway, it's hard to see what the alert could be if it's not coming from the ajax. If you just remove the `getg1();` call entirely, does it still reproduce the error?

Comment: Are you sure id="currentform" is not used somewhere else in whole script which is loaded with page? Not only in the script which you are showing us, I mean in whole script of your project which is loaded dynamically and creating this issue. try changing it's id.

Comment: @ADyson no, but then if you wait for the ajax to finish the error doesnt come - it seems to be the ajax returning perhaps either during the popup of the save the form, or around that click time.. although it seems to be immediate appearing of the error on the click.. like its interrupting it somehow

Comment: @NeerajKumar defo - you've the whole area in front of you - and while there is a master, its almost blank and contains a maincontent only - its the default one you get on a new asp.net web app

Comment: it potentially does interrupt it, yes, because you're kicking off a new HTTP request by clicking on the link - often that would cause your page to be destroyed and a new one loaded, which obviously kills all JS running in the page. Since this request happens to return a file to download, then obviously that doesn't end up happening. But I can see how it could be linked. Maybe trying putting `target="_blank"` in the `<a` tag so it opens the URL in another tab/window. Then it's less likely to interfere with the current page. Not 100% sure that will do it, but give it a go.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, quick FY: `$('#g1').click(function () { });` will add a *new* event handler, it won't override any existing event handlers.

Comment: @freedomn-m I was grabbing at straws :( it was worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking on the link, you're kicking off a new HTTP request. This is likely to interrupt any JS, including AJAX requests, currently running on the page. Normally clicking on a hyperlink (or submitting a form) would cause your page to be destroyed and a new one loaded, which obviously kills all JS running in the page.

Since this request happens to return a file to download, then obviously that doesn't end up happening. But it still is likely to interrupt the JS execution, in anticipation of getting a new HTML page from the server.

If you put

```
target="_blank"
```

in the `<a` tag so it opens the URL in another tab/window then opening the file should not interfere with the current page, because the browser is no longer expecting to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

From you code I can see that your code fetches from the URL you have sent the AJAX request.Although, I would advise you to check the response you are getting as error. console.log(xx) because obviously xx does not have an array with key 'responseText'. That us what is undefined.

Comment: Nope - as I said it works fine once all the ajax loads  have completed.  Watching the error log shows nothing appear when the error box does.

Comment: alert("error: " + xx.responseText); is the code executing on runtime. try logging xx and see what its value is. or simply put your function in document.ready

Comment: right, but there is no error.. and it happens on clicking a URL which shouldnt relate